# Does paraffin wax solidification makes melting point increase or decrease or none?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition, states-of-matter

Does paraffin wax on solidification makes temp increase or decrease?
Or it is not related to the solidification?

Comment: Why do you think it would change? It doesn't change for other matter like water?  As long as you have the same molecular structure, I imagine it would not change.

Comment: This is a good question. Wax doesn't have a molecular structure; it's an amorphous mixture of a variety of molecules of different lengths.  While liquefied, could it somehow separate or  partially separate, with the heavier components sinking to the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Practically all materials have a well-measured "heat of transition" at the liquid-solid transformation temperature.  This is the amount of energy per unit mass that is given off, without a change in temperature, as the liquid solidifies.  (same energy is required to convert from solid to liquid).  As to paraffin in particular, you can easily look up these parameters via wikipedia or CRC or similar references.